# RDP to other computers on the same vpn

Tags: vpn, azure, rdp

I have:

≡1 Laptop (Windows 10 pro)

≡1 Desktop (Windows 10 pro)

≡1 VM (Windows 10 Server 2017?)

I am able to RDP to the VM through the laptop via VPN (in Azure). I am also able to RDP into the VM through the Desktop on the same VPN.

Is it possible to connect to the Desktop from the Laptop through the same VPN from different physical locations? I am able to ping the VM from the Laptop, the VM from the Desktop, vice versa, but I can't ping the Desktop from the Laptop on the same VPN, vice versa. Theoretically they are on the same network right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### update

> Is it possible to connect to the Desktop from the Laptop through the
>   same VPN from different physical locations?

Yes, you can connect to the Desktop from the Laptop through the same VPN from different physical locations. You will get a virtual IP address that you can check under **the PPP adapter** VPN name using command **ipconfig** once you connect to the VPN. The virtual IP address was assigned from address pool when you set a point to site configuration.

I test in my lab. Client1 and Client2 connect to the same P2S VPN connection. The address pool for VPN conenction is 172.100.1.0/24 on the azure portal. Client1 was assigned the Allocated IP address 172.100.1.137; Client2 was assigned the Allocated IP address 172.100.1.129. You can see the screenshot as below:
[image]

> I am able to ping the VM from the Laptop, the VM from the Desktop,
>   vice versa, but I can't ping the Desktop from the Laptop on the same
>   VPN, vice versa. Theoretically they are on the same network right?

Yes, you are right, theoretically they are on the same network since they have the virtual IP address on the same address pool. You can ping the Desktop from the Laptop on the same VPN by using **virtual IP address** under the PPP adapter. I test it and the screenshots as below:
[image][image]

Comment: Thank you, Nancy Xiong! Yes we use the VPN gateway to connect to the VM securely in order to use remote apps on different computers. Also we route traffic just for the apps through the VPN for encryption since we are using QuickBooks Desktop. In theory, if I create a VPN to the desktop computer at home, will I be able to access other computers on the same network or VPN as well? Is that just because it’s a different type of VPN than Azure? Will I still be able to encrypt the connection/web traffic?

Comment: Yes, in theory, we can create a VPN at company or at home to access the computers remotely those are not on the same network over the internet. It is a different type of VPN than azure. Here is a example: https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/install-vpn-rras-remote-routing-access/